# Explicitly invoking constructors in PHP

Tags: php

Let me first clarify that I'm not much familiar with PHP language, since I have been working with Java web and Android. Following is a simple PHP class where I'm trying to invoke explicitly a parameterized constructor.

```
final class Demo
{
    private $x;
    private $y;             

    public function __constructor($x, $y)
    {
        $this->x=$x;
        $this->y=$y;                
    }   

    public function show()
    {
        echo "Sum = ", $this->x+$this->y;   
    }
}

$d=new Demo(10, 20);
$d->show();
```

It however displays `Sum = 0` means that the constructor is not being invoked (In Java, C# and languages alike, it's very handy to invoke constructors somewhat in such way). How can I then invoke the specified parameterized constructor in the above class?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but to be fair: The question is fairly simple solveable using https://www.google.com/?q=php+constructor The first answer http://php.net/language.oop5.decon Regarding the tooltip of the downvote arrow: "This question does not show any research effort"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of the constructor is `__construct()`. `__constructor()` is just a curious looking method.

Comment: Means that I need to do something like this `$d=new Demo(); $d->__constructor(10,20);`

Comment: No, just rename your `__constructor()` into `__construct()`. In PHP, the construtor function name is `__construct()`.